# Delete duplicate top-level folder names from list with batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete duplicate folder names from a folder list. The duplicates occur when there's more than 1 subfolder. I end up with a list like below. I want to get rid of any line that has a sub2 folder.

folder1\sub1
folder2\sub1
folder2\sub1\sub2
folder3\sub1

Following code works if there is only one sub2 foldername, but it's awkward--hopeless if more than one sub2. There's gotta be a better way. Any help much appreciated.

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    :: Write the sub2 foldernames to a tmp file
    For /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%I IN (folderlist.txt) DO Echo %%I >>temp.tmp

    :: Set var for each sub2 name in tmp file and 
    :: call routine to write lines that don't contain that name
    For /f %%G in (temp.tmp) do (
        Set findstring=%%G
        CALL :FindDup
    )
EXIT

:findDup            
    For /f %%H in ('Type folderlist.txt ^|Find "!findstring!" /v') Do (
        Echo %%H >> NoDup.txt
    )
exit /b
```

FWIW:   I'm using this command to generate the list, then deleting the path preceding folder1, folder2, etc

```
    For /d %%G in (*) do dir /ad /on /s /b "%%G" >> folderlist.txt
```

Comment: so, you want to remove all the second level folder, right?

Comment: Well, the line that has the second level folder, yes. Want each folder listed once with it's 1st level sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there, if you just want the resulting list after eliminating the subfolders, just try to echo the appropiate lines to the list file, having copied it first into a temporary.

```
move folderlist.txt %temp%\folders.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=\" %%a in (%temp%\folders.txt) do (
   if .%%c==. echo %%a\%%b >>folderlist.txt
)
```

if you want to remove the folder from the disk, then change the line to

```
if not .%%c==. rd /s %%a\%%b\%%c
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q20840158.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=\" %%b IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%c"=="" ECHO(%%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q20840158.txt` containing your data for my testing.

But - It's really unclear what you mean by a "duplicate". How precisely do **you** define a duplicate in this context?

Comment: Yes, imprecise, I suppose. In example, folder2 is listed twice. So I meant some "top level" folder names are duplicated because there are separate lines for subs, sub/subs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
COPY NUL newfile.txt >NUL 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q20840158.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /I /L /g:"newfile.txt" >NUL 2>NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 >>"newfile.txt" ECHO(%%a
)

TYPE newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q20840158.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

Ah- you want to make sure that any additions to the list don't contain a previous entry...

Comment: Much better than my contortions but this still only deletes the line with the first sub2. What if my example includes lines for `Folder4\sub1` and `Folder4\sub1\sub2`? (and BTW, all names are different; the sub2 names aren't the same. thx